# Create multi setUp methods in nosetests

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

I'm trying to do some thing like this code, But according to the nose doc, @with_setup isn't working INSIDE class which is inheriting from TestCase.

so is there a way to create multi setup methods in the same class?

```
from nose.tools import with_setup
from unittest import TestCase


class TestcontaineridAPI(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        print(' Original setup method.')

    def setup_update(self):
        print(' 00000000 ')

    @with_setup(setup=setup_update)
    def test_fun(self):
        print('1212')
```

Comment: is it possible to call your setup methods inside your test function body?

Comment: of course not cause nosetests call setup and execute it then call the testcase

Comment: If you need 2 different setup methods I'd write two different TestClasses/TestCases